# SKMaps crashes when add SKViaPoint

Tags: ios, xcode, skmaps

I'm using SKMaps to simulate custom routes. It was working fine with navigating a point to another point, I mean use start and destination only:

```
route.startCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167)
route.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9677, 23.7567)
```

but if I add viaPoints to route, app will crash when I startNavigation:

```
route.startCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167)
route.viaPoints = [SKViaPoint(1, withCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9672, 23.7367))]    
route.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9677, 23.7567)
```

Here is the only log I got:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
```

If anyone saw it before or know how to fix it, please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: We'll investigate this. Can you please add in what environment have you tested? SDK 2.5.1?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the newest version 2.5.1, xcode 7. It crashes on every devices. Even with the demo project (swift).

Comment: Can you please also add the code you are using for adding the viaPoint array? (maybe the problem is with the viaPoint array initialization)

Comment: I was testing in the demo project:  
1. add this to SKMaps.h:  
  
#import "SKViaPoint.h"  
#import "SKViaPointState.h"  
2. add 1 line to RoutingViewController.swift (after line 81):<br/>
<br/>
route.startCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167)<br/>
// Add this line:  
route.viaPoints = [SKViaPoint(1, withCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9672, 23.7367))]<br/>
route.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9677, 23.7567)<br/>

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in 2.5.1, that is fixed now. You can get the new build from here: [forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7315-SKViaPoint-crashes-FIXED](http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7315-SKViaPoint-crashes-FIXED)